# I want to make a list of list in python in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I want to get an output like

```py
['a','aa','aaa','aaaa','aaaaa'],['b','bb','bbb','bbbb','bbbbb'],['c','cc','ccc','cccc','ccccc']
```

using the code snippet below

```py
    a = ["a","b","g","f"]
    b =[1,2,3,4,5]
    e = []
    f = []
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            e.append(i*j)

        f.append(e)
    print(f)
```

Can anybody help me with this please

Comment: `[[x*y  for x in b] for y in a]`

Answer (score 2):

You're failing to reset `e` to a new empty `list` after each outer loop, so you're inserting a bunch of aliases to the same `list`. Just move the `e = []` between the two `for`s (and indent to match), e.g.:

```
for i in a:
    e = []
    for j in b:
        ...
```

so you make a new `list` to populate on each loop.

Alternatively, as noted in the comments, a nested listcomp would do the trick:

```
f = [[x * y for x in b] for y in a]
```

removing the need for a named `e` at all (and running somewhat faster to boot).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to reset you e list with every iteration. This will yield your desired outcome:

```
a = ["a","b","g","f"]
b =[1,2,3,4,5]
e = []
f = []
for i in a:
    e= []
    for j in b:
        e.append(i*j)
    f.append(e)
print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only error is that you are not resetting `e` to `[]` after each iteration in a. Let me explain:

This is the code you need:

```py
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        e.append(i*j)

    f.append(e)
    e = []
```

You need the `e = []` at the end. If there was no `e = []`, at the end of the**first** iteration, e = ['a', 'aa'...]. During the second iteration, e would equal [a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa, b, bb, bbb...] However, setting it to an empty list stops this.

Comment: Thankyou so much @The Pilot Dude

Comment: No worries I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Python has a property that if u multiply a number with a string it will multiply that string for example:

```
print(2*"ab")
```

> abab

You can use this for your answer:

```
a = ["a","b","g","f"]
b =[1,2,3,4,5]
c = [[x*y  for x in b] for y in a]
print(c)
```

Comment: Thankyou @Kumar Aditya

Comment: The OP clearly understood sequence multiplication; they were using that intentionally in their original code...

Answer (score 1):

Lengthy, but this works fine too

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
nest_array = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    arr = []
    for val in b:
        str1 = ""
        while len(str1) < val:
            if len(str1) == val:
                break
            else:
                str1 += a[i]
        arr.append(str1)
    nest_array.append(arr)
print(nest_array)
```